# Kneading low-carb bread with large percentage vital wheat gluten

Tags: baking, bread, kneading, low-carb, vital-wheat-gluten

I'm trying to make a low-glycemic bread.  I've tried several keto recipes and also experimented -- I'm basically not happy with anything (too rubbery, too tall, too flat, weird taste, etc.). I've decided I need to understand the science (since bread-making is a science, after all!), but I can't find anything online that explains how to work with "vital wheat gluten" as one's dominent flour (i.e., e.g., mixed w/ oat fiber & flax).  In regular wheat flour, kneading combines the two proteins *gliadin* and *glutenin*, forming strands of "gluten." Kneading warms the dough so the proteins expand during fermentation and bond.  But is "vital wheat gluten" called "gluten" because the gliadin & glutenin are already bonded?? Does it need to be "developed"? Do I knead MORE or LESS or the SAME with this "gluten"?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vital wheat gluten is made by [washing out the gluten of flour which has already been kneaded and hydrated](https://www.alphafoodie.com/how-to-make-vital-wheat-gluten-and-wheat-flour-starch/).  As such, the gluten in it should already be fully developed.

Comment: That "recipe" you gave the link for gives me exactly the info I've been looking for FOREVER!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: It's what we're here for!  Always glad when we can help.

Comment: Oh, if this is the "right" answer for you, remember to select it.

Comment: I tried to!  But I don't have enough "points" yet, or whatever they're called.  I"ll keep trying.

Comment: If you asked the question, you can definitely select the answer.

Comment: Aha!  There you go!

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing special to vital wheat gluten. When you mix it with a low-gluten or no-gluten flour, it acts pretty much as a flour which has had the gluten inside from the beginning. So, adjust your gluten percentage to what you want it to be - around 9% would be a good match for AP flour - and use it as normal, kneading the same as a normal wheat flour.

A side note: starch is a major contributor to the fluffiness of bread, while gluten on its own gives you a rubbery texture. So don't expect to mix gluten with a random keto powder and get a bread that's exactly like wheat bread. By tweaking the recipe - experimenting with different "filler" fibers, different gluten-to-fiber ratio, adding more or less fat - you'll likely get something interesting. Just don't be discouraged when your first attempt is far from perfect.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  This isn't really what I was asking about, though.  The info I can't find anywhere is about whether the two proteins gliadin and glutenin are already bonded in "vital wheat gluten" -- is that why it's called "gluten"?  In that case, it would not need to be kneaded as much.  The "flours" for many low-carb/low-glycemic breads are made with 50-75% VWG and then the remainder can be various things -- oat fiber, chickpea or almond flour, etc., i.e. things with zero gluten.  So that's the kneading question:  If VWG is most of my "flour," how much kneading does it need?